Relevance of balanced covariates for unbiased estimates in OLS regression
In my field of economics, many papers I’ve come across rely heavily on observational data for analysis. However, I've noticed that it's uncommon for researchers to explicitly address whether the covariates or "control variables" in their regression models are balanced between treatment and control groups.
For instance, consider a study examining the effect of Research and Development (R&D) spending on firm performance. Typically, researchers would collect data on various firm characteristics believed to influence performance, using them as control variables. However, aside from other potential biases, it often seems that little attention is paid to whether these control variables are balanced between firms that engage in R&D and those that do not. Researchers seem more focused on including controls rather than ensuring balance.
Recently, I came across a paper that took a different approach. It examined the impact of the founder's gender on a dependent variable, Y. The authors addressed potential covariate imbalances by using propensity score matching. They created a matched sample where the control variables were not significantly different between firms with male and female founders, ensuring comparability between the groups. This seems like a more rigorous approach to dealing with potential confounding factors, which I haven’t seen applied as often in other studies.
Do unbalanced covariates in a regression introduce bias, or why would achieving balance be advantageous? In theory, regression models account for differences in control variables, but perhaps imbalance could lead to more subtle biases or inefficiencies that matching methods address more effectively.
